# Google Cloud Login Widget like Facebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, google-cloud-platform, widget

I am creating a solution for my customers. This solution will allow them to check SEO parameters of their websites. This requires a script to be executed on Linux instance. However, I want them to use their own Google Account. The work flow should look like this:

Let's my website is www.example.com.

1. Customers open www.example.com on their browser
2. On my home page there is widget that allows them to login into their Google  Account
3. Once they have logged in - I should be able to use their security tokens to launch an Linux instance
4. Then my script for grabbing SEO parameters would run on their Linux instance.

Limitations:

1. I know it can be done using their API keys / secret but I want a widget much like FaceBook widget (that allows particular APP to run)
2. I don't want to burn my cash running the script for their websites.

Is there any that can be done like this?

I am also open to alternatives as long as I don't spent money on compute.

Comment: You have it backward in Google Cloud. When you use OAuth in your project, you are granting the user permission to YOUR project, not the other way around. You will need to create a billing account and project for that user so that they are billed. Then you would create OAuth Client ID/Secrets to access their account.

Comment: Ok. This is a great insight. Thanks. 

Ok. This is how I am envisioning the solution:

1. Use Billing API to create a billing account
2. ONce account has been created 
3. Add projects under those billing account
4. And then when customer use our service - they will get billed

Comment: I did find an API to add Cloud Billing Account. But I don't see a way (using API - I want to remove any manual work) to associate it with a Payment method. Any help would be appreciated.